# Swift how do I scrape top 500 or 1000 top websites from a live website?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, web-scraping, scrapy

First, I don't know is it appropriate to scrape data from https://gtmetrix.com/top1000.html, but I want to get the list of top 500 or 1000 websites for my app. So when the user searches a certain website, the app could provide the suggested result.

I am trying to get the html content of this website by the following code

```
        let url = URL(string:"https://gtmetrix.com/top1000.html")
    do{
         let html = try String(contentsOf: url!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
        print(html)
    }catch {
        print("woops")
    }
```

But the html string seems inconsistent and doesn't contain the information I want, for example, the missing parts between tag tbody and /tbody should include the info I need. I can see the content by using developer tools in Chrome.

Does that mean the data here is protective and it is not allowed to scrape?

Are there any other resources and methods to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

```html
  <table id="top-1000" class="t1k-table styled-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="t1k-rank">Rank</th>
        <th class="t1k-url">URL</th>
        <th class="t1k-pagespeed">PageSpeed</th>
        <th class="t1k-yslow">YSlow</th>
        <th class="t1k-time">Onload</th>
        <th class="t1k-time">Fully Loaded</th>
        <th class="t1k-elements">Requests</th>
        <th class="t1k-size">Total Size</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: if I use the following code, got the same html content.        
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as Any)
 }.resume()

Comment: I just checked that site, and as I suspected, it populates the table asynchronously (with client-side code). Try opening the Network tab and see what the data is in the first document that you get. On the bright side, the client-sides calls into an API which returns a JSON.